# jQuery selector does not have specific data attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I have an attribute being applied to my dynamically created divs called `data-product`. Is there a selector I can use to select all divs without a specific `data-product` value? For instance, if one of the data-product values is "radio," is there a way I can select every div with a data-product value that does not equal radio?

```
<div data-product="radio" class="product"></div>
<div data-product="television" class="product"></div>
<div data-product="speakers" class="product"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you want

```
$(".product[data-product!='radio']")
```

or

```
$(".product:not([data-product='radio'])")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can either use jQuery's proprietary [attribute-not-equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector):

```
$('div.product[data-product!="radio"]')
```

Or if you prefer a more standards-based selector (i.e. one that can be used in CSS), use `:not()` with a regular attribute selector:

```
$('div.product:not([data-product="radio"])')
```